# Query Access Question

Tags: vba

With one table `tblBids` containing `BidId` field with the relationship `bidID` has multiple contractors from `tblContractors`, I am trying to create a query which will list each contractor and email address related to their `BidID`.

```
BidID      Contractor Name     Contractor Email
1          Contractor A        Contractor A Email
1          Contractor B        Contractor B Email
2          Contractor A        Contractor A Email
2          Contractor C        Contractor C Email
```

My goal is to create a Send Object Command to send a PDF Report out for say `BidID` 1 to all contractors selected to that Bid ID.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This answer presumes there is no many to many table with BidId related to ContractorId which should probably exist.  Examples of the tables from which you are querying are as helpful as seeing the example of expected result.

```
DECLARE @BidId int = 1

    SELECT BidID, ContractorName, ContractorEmail 
    FROM tblBids B
    JOIN tblContractors C
    ON B.ContractorId = C.ContractorId 
    WHERE B.BidId = @BidId
```

Comment: So create another table that is a many to many relationship?

Comment: Yes - Bid information should be in one table, contractor information in another table and a many to many table with their respective ids can link them.  In this way, if a contractor changes their email, you would only need to update the single contractor information row.  If information on a bid changes, you would only need to change the single bid row.  While not getting carried away, the normal forms (3rd) are a good place to start for the type of query/application functionality you appear to be building:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: I have now been able to build that query and it sorts it properly thanks! Now how can I build a DoCmd to send that report to those emails? I figure I am going to need a filter command to filter out the ID Number that is in the form and then create a String to place all of the emails in the the BCC area

Comment: if you are using vba, then just loop through the recordset returned from your query to concatenate the email strings together.

Comment: how would this VBA look?Private Sub Command25_Click()

DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "rptProposal", acFormatPDF, , , strEmail, "Proposal", "Attached please find our prosal"

Comment: yes.  In the strEmail, you would want to have your concatenated list of Contractor emails collected.  Might have better luck asking this as separate question on stackoverflow rather than dba.stackexchange